# MessageBox showing data entered into windows form from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to create a messagebox that will let the end user see what information they've just entered and saved into a windows form I created in visual studio 2010 using C#. I used the details textboxes as the header from the parent table I dragged onto the form, and the DataGridView from the child table that I dragged to the form. 
Here's the relevant part of the code and what I've tried so far:

```
    private void tblReceiptBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.tblReceiptBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.inventoryBDataSet);

       /*MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The record you entered:\nReceipt ID: {0}\nReceipt Date:   {1}\nEmployee ID: {2:0000}\n" + "Receipt Detail ID: {3:0000}\nStock ID: {4:0000}\nReceipt Quantity: {5}\nhas been successfully saved.", receiptIDTextBox.Text, receiptDateDateTimePicker.Text,employeeIDTextBox.Text.ToUpper(), dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.ToString(),dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.ToString(), dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.ToString()));*/

        this.employeeIDTextBox.Focus();

    }
```

I have three fields in the DataGridView that I'd like to include in the String.Format, but there doesn't seem to be a way to reach that information. I'd appreciate it if anyone had any suggestions, as I'm new to Visual Studio and C#. Thanks.

Comment: A `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` hosts a collection of `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` cells. If you want to print a value of a particular cell you need to find the DataGridViewTextBoxCell in the current `DataGridViewRow` or are just interested in the HeaderText property of the column?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm looking for the value in each cell. I'll check out the DataGridViewTextBoxCell properties. I guess I wasn't exactly sure what to look for. Thanks !